# Navigation Drawer Lag in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

**What I Have**

I have a Navigation Drawer and a View Pager. The View Pager have got 5 fragments. I have placed one Image View in each of the fragments in the View Pager.

**The Problem**

I see that whenever I place the Image View in the fragment and try to open the Navigation Drawer, the animation is very slow and laggy. Even when I try to close it its very very laggy.

But if I remove the ImageView then the Navigaiton is smooth as usual.

I need to place the ImageView as it is very important. Please give some solutions as how cal I make the Navigation Drawer open & close smoothly?

Comment: Could u please share ur code

Comment: @thestalker Which code do you specifically need? Actually the codes are very long to paste here.

Comment: the code containing viewpager and navigation drawer along with xml...try this https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/DrawerWithTabsAndViewPager...

Answer (score 1):

I was facing almost the same issue. I tried using Handler for calling the fragment after closing the drawer. But it didn't solve my problem. Then i found a solution. I used the [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library. Simply loaded the imageViews using this library and now my animations and super smooth !

Here's a sample code : instead of using

```
 imageView.setImageResource(image);
```

use :

```
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
 .load(images)
 .into(imageView);
```

Glide Source Link:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: This worked for me, use .fitcenter(). to center your icons if you need to like I did.